# Dimensions of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations

> Let $T:\mathbb R^3$ maps to $\mathbb {R}^2$ be a linear transformation defined by 
>   $$T(x,y,z)=(x+y,x-z)$$
>   Then the dimension of the null space of $T$ is ?

As I solved this:
The possible row reduction gives 2 pivot hence 2 pivot columns I.e the no. Of linearly independent vectors is 2. Those two independent vectors I.e.$(1,1,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$ make the basis hence the dimensions (no. Of basis) is 2.

But answer given is 1. What's wrong with that?

Comment: What’s wrong is that you’ve confused the null space of the matrix with its row space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Matrix A associated to T is:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1  & 0\\
1 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$rank(A) = 2 \implies null(A)=3-2=1$$

Comment: Can't we find the dimensions by using pivots and basis ??

Comment: Yes of course, #pivots = # of basis vectors = Rank(A)=2, thus $n-2=1=dim(null(A))$.

Comment: And all independent basis makes the no. Of dimensions right? But I had gone through an MIT online lecture ..N there was a 4×5 matrix and they find out  3 basis vectors .But they ended up that no. Of basis vectors for the subspace represents dimensions for that space....So dimension is 3.......Why not n-r

Comment: When we consider $Ax$ we are dealing with the image of $T$ that is the column space of $A$. Thus, the numer of linearly independent columns ($=rank(A)$) is the dimension of the column space that is the dimension of the image of T. The dimension of the null space is equal to $n-r$. In the case of 4-by-5 matrix with rank=3 the dimension of the column space is 3 and the dimension of the null space is 5-3=2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

Comment: thanku so much...You made my head clear of any doubt. Thanks for ur valuable time.

Answer (score 2):

The dimension of the null space (1) added to the dimension of the image (2) gives the number of columns (3). The vectors you found are a basis for the image.

Comment: Best answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

Or, a little more directly, the "null space" of a linear transformation, A, is defined as the set of all v such that Av= 0.  It is easy to show that the null space is a subspace of the domain space so has some dimension.

In the example given, with $A= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ we have $Av= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}x+ y \\ x- z\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.  That gives the equations x+ y= 0, x- z= 0.  Two equations cannot be solved for specific values of three unknowns.  What we can do is write y= -x, z= x so any such vector must be of the form $\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}x \\ -x \\ x\end{bmatrix}= x\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.  That shows that the null space has basis $\{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\}$ and so has dimension 1.

The "rank" of a linear transformation, by the way, is the dimension of the image of the domain space in the range space.  That is, it is the dimension of the space of all $\begin{bmatrix}u \\ v \end{bmatrix}$ such that there **exist** $\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}$ with $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}x+ y \\ x- z\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}u \\ v \end{bmatrix}$.  That is, there are x, y, and z, not necessarily unique, such that x+ y= u and x- z= v. Given any u and v, we could take x= u, y= 0, z= u- v.  Since we *can* find such x, y, z for **any** u, v, the rank is 2.